# How to debug with vs-code and ts-node in a typescript monorepo without compile typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, monorepo

I init a monorepo with lerna.

The monorepo has 2 packages: `@mono/util1`, `@mono/util2`. And `util1` and `util2` are linked to root node_modules as I wish:

[image]

util2 depends on util1

[image]

The 2 packages both have a `src` dir and a `dist` dir. Before I run tsc, the dist dirs are both empty.

The 2 packages both have `"main": "dist/index.js"` in their `package.json`.

Here comes the problem: when I run `node -r ts-node/register packages/util2/src/index.ts` with vs-code debugger, it throws an error: `Error: Cannot find module '@mono/util1'`

This is because in root `node_modules/@mono/util1/package.json`, its main filed is `dist/index.js`. Now I want when util2 import util1, it can resolve to `node_modules/@mono/util1/src/index.ts`not to `node_modules/@mono/util1/dist/index.js`. What should I do?